# GWT DatePicker Keyboard Navigation

Tags: gwt, datepicker

I have a GWT datepicker and I am trying to make this accessible from the keyboard. I am having difficulty in exposing the actual date elements in the calendar and I was wondering if anyone has had any luck with this? All I want really is to be able to tab into the different dates in the calendar.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem is exposing the elements in the calendar so that I can use the tabindex on them

Comment: I took a quickly look at the `DefaultCalendarView.java` file and I saw this : *"Simple calendar view. Not extensible as we wish to evolve it freely over time."*

Comment: Do you have any update on this?

Comment: We have just deployed GWT 2.5 on our application so when I get the chance to look at this I'll post back

Answer (score 1):

Strangely. If you launch - http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwDatePicker

```
Tab Click 1 - ?
Tab Click 2 - GWT Homepage
Tab Click 3 - More Examples
Tab Click 4 - Country/I18N seleciton
Tab Click 5 and Click Enter key - Month Change on Datepicker
Tab Click 6 and Click Enter key - Date 1 gets selected for current month
Tab Click 7 and Click Enter key - Date 2 gets selected for current month
.
.
.so on
```

**`The keyboard support with tabindex seems to work with embedded DatePicker`**!!! Tested it on FireFox and Chrome. It seems only cell highlighting needs to be done to improve User Interaction!!!!!!!!!

**`Sadly this is not feasible with Tabpanel or Datebox's popup Datepicker ( hides on tab click ).`**

GWT had some interesting ideas on it @ http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/wiki/accessibility

It has now got a broader scope @ [Dev Guide on Accessibility](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideA11y)
However, the new scope on accessibility does not list/mention out datepicker or keyboard access.

Comment: That's a very interesting find! I still find it surprising that accessibility isn't built into GWT. It's good to know they are looking into it, maybe in the next release this will be sorted

Comment: I track their svn on a monthly basis. It is not exactly encouraging w.r.t to Keyboard support. It varied across widgets and Grid has some cool keyboard support. The issue - keyboard support is not intuitive. Duly note that Keyboard support is only a subset of "Accessibility".